# Which methods can be used to manage differing versions of pre-existing databases?

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-assets

**Note** this is intended to be a *Ask and Answer Your Own Questions* as per  [share your knowledge, Q&A-style](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/07/01/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/)

Often a pre-existing database is provided for an Android App that utilises SQLite. The database is often placed into the assets folder and the App will copy the database if it does not exist.

For a newer version of the App changing the database in the assets folder is fine as the changed database will be copied. However, when upgrading an App from a previous version the database will exist and therefore it will not be copied, nor can it easily be seamlessly deleted to enable a copy from the assets folder.

A further complexity can arise if user data needs to be preserved.

For example I originally deploy a database with a single table with 3 columns created with :-

```
CREATE TABLE "user" (
  "_id" INTEGER NOT NULL,
  "user" TEXT,
  "password" TEXT,
  PRIMARY KEY ("_id")
)
```

That contains data such as :-

[image]

And the next incarnation of the App wants to utilise a changed schema, with an extra column and a UNIQUE constraint on the **user** column such as :-

```
CREATE TABLE "user" (
  "_id" INTEGER NOT NULL,
  "user" TEXT,
  "password" TEXT,
  "email" TEXT,
  PRIMARY KEY ("_id"),
  CONSTRAINT "user" UNIQUE ("user")
);
```

And additionally additional data is also added e.g. it is now :-

[image]

The user has had the ability to add their own data, which needs to be preserved. So deleting the database file, even if possible, would delete the user's data.

**What methods can be used to manage differing versions of pre-existing databases?**

Comment: I find this Q&A interesting: It offers a viable solution to a common problem. I can't get why the question has been downvoted.

Comment: @Fantômas no idea as to why and thanks for adding the Android tag.

Comment: ... and removing it from the title... :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short one way would be to copy the new asset file to the appropriate location, whilst keeping a copy of the original database file you can then apply the updates in order to effectively preserve the user's data to the newly copied database. **BUT** only if the App is being upgraded for that specific change and if the database exists.

If the database doesn't exist then the standard copy of the asset file should be undertaken.

## Here's an example of how this could be done.

This example relies quite heavily on a routines that allow management and some interrogation of the file in the assets folder and or the database file itself.

A class namely **DBAssetHandler.java** caters for the above (as well as an ability to extract the user_version AKA the Database Version when using the SQLiteOpenHelper).

- Note the class has also been tested on, and therefore caters for, Android Pie, and thus Write-Ahead logging (WAL the default in Pie) a well as journal mode, the previous default.
- Also note that if using WAL, then you should ensure the the database is fully check-pointed [see - Write-Ahead Logging](https://www.sqlite.org/wal.html)

it is :-

```
public class DBAssetHandler {

    static final String[] tempfiles = new String[]{"-journal","-wal","-shm"}; // temporary files to rename
    public static final String backup = "-backup"; //value to be appended to file name when renaming (psuedo delete)
    public static final  int OUCH = -666666666;

    /**
     * Check if the database already exists. NOTE will create the databases folder is it doesn't exist
     * @return true if it exists, false if it doesn't
     */
    public static boolean checkDataBase(Context context, String dbname) {

        File db = new File(context.getDatabasePath(dbname).getPath()); //Get the file name of the database
        Log.d("DBPATH","DB Path is " + db.getPath()); //TODO remove if publish App
        if (db.exists()) return true; // If it exists then return doing nothing

        // Get the parent (directory in which the database file would be)
        File dbdir = db.getParentFile();
        // If the directory does not exits then make the directory (and higher level directories)
        if (!dbdir.exists()) {
            db.getParentFile().mkdirs();
            dbdir.mkdirs();
        }
        return false;
    }


    /**
     * Copy database file from the assets folder
     * (long version caters for asset file name being different to the database name)
     * @param context           Context is needed to get the applicable package
     * @param dbname            name of the database file
     * @param assetfilename     name of the asset file
     * @param deleteExistingDB  true if an existing database file should be deleted
     *                              note will delete journal and wal files
     *                              note doen't actually delete the files rater it renames
     *                              the files by appended -backup to the file name
     *                              SEE/USE clearForceBackups below to delete the renamed files
     */
    public static void copyDataBase(Context context, String dbname, String assetfilename, boolean deleteExistingDB) {

        final String TAG = "COPYDATABASE";
        int stage = 0, buffer_size = 4096, blocks_copied = 0, bytes_copied = 0;
        File f = new File(context.getDatabasePath(dbname).toString());
        InputStream is;
        OutputStream os;

        /**
         * If forcing then effectively delete (rename) current database files
         */
        if (deleteExistingDB) {
            //String[] tempfiles = new String[]{"-journal","-wal","-shm"};
            //String backup = "-backup";
            f.renameTo(context.getDatabasePath(dbname + "-backup"));
            for (String s: tempfiles) {
                File tmpf = new File(context.getDatabasePath(dbname + s).toString());
                if (tmpf.exists()) {
                    tmpf.renameTo(context.getDatabasePath(dbname + s + backup));
                }
            }
        }


        //Open your local db as the input stream
        Log.d(TAG,"Initiated Copy of the database file " + assetfilename + " from the assets folder."); //TODO remove if publishing
        try {
            is = context.getAssets().open(assetfilename); // Open the Asset file
            stage++;
            Log.d(TAG, "Asset file " + assetfilename + " found so attmepting to copy to " + f.getPath()); //TODO remove if publishing

            os = new FileOutputStream(f);
            stage++;
            //transfer bytes from the inputfile to the outputfile
            byte[] buffer = new byte[buffer_size];
            int length;
            while ((length = is.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                blocks_copied++;
                Log.d(TAG, "Attempting copy of block " + String.valueOf(blocks_copied) + " which has " + String.valueOf(length) + " bytes."); //TODO remove if publishing
                os.write(buffer, 0, length);
                bytes_copied += length;
            }
            stage++;
            Log.d(TAG,
                    "Finished copying Database " + dbname +
                            " from the assets folder, to  " + f.getPath() +
                            String.valueOf(bytes_copied) + "were copied, in " +
                            String.valueOf(blocks_copied) + " blocks of size " +
                            String.valueOf(buffer_size) + "."
            ); //TODO remove if publishing
            //Close the streams
            os.flush();
            stage++;
            os.close();
            stage++;
            is.close();
            Log.d(TAG, "All Streams have been flushed and closed.");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            String exception_message = "";
            e.printStackTrace();
            switch (stage) {
                case 0:
                    exception_message = "Error trying to open the asset " + dbname;
                    break;
                case 1:
                    exception_message = "Error opening Database file for output, path is " + f.getPath();
                    break;
                case 2:
                    exception_message = "Error flushing written database file " + f.getPath();
                    break;
                case 3:
                    exception_message = "Error closing written database file " + f.getPath();
                    break;
                case 4:
                    exception_message = "Error closing asset file " + f.getPath();

            }
            throw new RuntimeException("Unable to copy the database from the asset folder." + exception_message + " see starck-trace above.");
        }
    }

    /**
     * Copy the databsse from the assets folder where asset name and dbname are the same
     * @param context
     * @param dbname
     * @param deleteExistingDB
     */
    public static void copyDataBase(Context context, String dbname, boolean deleteExistingDB) {
        copyDataBase(context, dbname,dbname,deleteExistingDB);
    }

    /**
     * Get the SQLite_user_vesrion from the DB in the asset folder
     *
     * @param context           needed to get the appropriate package assets
     * @param assetfilename     the name of the asset file (assumes/requires name matches database)
     * @return                  the version number as stored in the asset DB
     */
    public static int getVersionFromDBInAssetFolder(Context context, String assetfilename) {
        InputStream is;
        try {
            is = context.getAssets().open(assetfilename);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            return OUCH;
        }
        return getDBVersionFromInputStream(is);
    }

    /**
     * Get the version from the database itself without opening the database as an SQliteDatabase
     * @param context   Needed to ascertain package
     * @param dbname    the name of the dataabase
     * @return          the version number extracted
     */
    public static int getVersionFromDBFile(Context context, String dbname) {
        InputStream is;
        try {
            is = new FileInputStream(new File(context.getDatabasePath(dbname).toString()));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            return OUCH;
        }
        return getDBVersionFromInputStream(is);
    }

    /**
     * Get the Database Version (user_version) from an inputstream
     *  Note the inputstream is closed
     * @param is    The Inputstream
     * @return      The extracted version number
     */
    private static int getDBVersionFromInputStream(InputStream is) {
        int rv = -1, dbversion_offset = 60, dbversion_length = 4 ;
        byte[] dbfileheader = new byte[64];
        byte[] dbversion = new byte[4];
        try {
            is.read(dbfileheader);
            is.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return rv;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < dbversion_length; i++ ) {
            dbversion[i] = dbfileheader[dbversion_offset + i];
        }
        return ByteBuffer.wrap(dbversion).getInt();
    }

    /**
     * Check to see if the asset file exists
     *
     * @param context           needed to get the appropriate package
     * @param assetfilename     the name of the asset file to check
     * @return                  true if the asset file exists, else false
     */
    public static boolean ifAssetFileExists(Context context, String assetfilename) {
        try {
            context.getAssets().open(assetfilename);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }


    /**
     * Delete the backup
     * @param context
     * @param dbname
     */
    public static void clearForceBackups(Context context, String dbname) {
        String[] fulllist = new String[tempfiles.length + 1];

        for (int i = 0;i < tempfiles.length; i++) {
            fulllist[i] = tempfiles[i];
        }
        fulllist[tempfiles.length] = ""; // Add "" so database file backup is also deleted
        for (String s: fulllist) {
            File tmpf = new File(context.getDatabasePath(dbname + s + backup).toString());
            if (tmpf.exists()) {
                tmpf.delete();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

- Hopefully the method names and comments should explain the above code.

The assets files, there are two :-

- **pev1.db** - the original pre-existing database as described above
- **pev1mod.db** - the modified (extra column, UNIQUE constraint and the additional row).

The Database Helper (a subclass of SQLOpenHelper) namely **PEV2DBHelper.java**, It should be noted that the Database Version (**DBVERSION**) is used to control and is as such distinct from the APK's version (which may change more frequently than the DB)

- issues were found when trying to use the **onUpgrade** method, therefore an alternative approach, that of getting the databases's **user_version** from the file rather than via an SQLiteDatabase.

Here is **PEV2DBHelper.java** :-

```
/**
 * MORE COMPLEX EXAMPLE RETAINING USER DATA
 */
public class PEV2DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public static final String DBNAME = "pev1.db";
    public static final String ASSETTOCOPY_DBV2 = "pev1mod.db"; //<<<<<<<<<< changed DB
    public static final int DBVERSION = 2; //<<<<<<<<<< increase and db file from assets will copied keeping existing data
    Context mContext;

    public PEV2DBHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DBNAME, null, DBVERSION);


        int dbversion = DBAssetHandler.getVersionFromDBFile(context,DBNAME);
        Log.d("DBFILEVERSION","Database File Version = " + String.valueOf(dbversion));
        int af1version = DBAssetHandler.getVersionFromDBInAssetFolder(context,DBNAME);
        Log.d("DBFILEVERSION","Asset Database File Version = " + String.valueOf(af1version));
        int af2version = DBAssetHandler.getVersionFromDBInAssetFolder(context,ASSETTOCOPY_DBV2);
        Log.d("DBFILEVERSION","Asset Database File Version = " + String.valueOf(af2version));

        // cater for different DBVERSIONS (for testing )
        if (!DBAssetHandler.checkDataBase(context,DBNAME)) {

            //If new installation of the APP then copy the appropriate asset file for the DB
            switch (DBVERSION) {
                case 1:
                    DBAssetHandler.copyDataBase(context,DBNAME,DBNAME,false);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    DBAssetHandler.copyDataBase(context,DBNAME,ASSETTOCOPY_DBV2,false);
                    break;
            }
        }

        // If DBVERSION upgraded to 2 with modified DB but wanting to preserve used data
        if (DBAssetHandler.checkDataBase(context,DBNAME) & (DBVERSION > DBAssetHandler.getVersionFromDBFile(context, DBNAME)) & (DBVERSION == 2) ) {

            String[] oldcolumns = new String[]{"user","password"};

            // Copy in the new DB noting that delete option renames old (truue flag important)
            DBAssetHandler.copyDataBase(context,DBNAME,ASSETTOCOPY_DBV2,true);

            //Get the newly copied database
            SQLiteDatabase newdb = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(context.getDatabasePath(DBNAME).toString(),null,SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
            //Get the old database (backup copy)
            SQLiteDatabase olddb =  SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(context.getDatabasePath(DBNAME + DBAssetHandler.backup).toString(),null,SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);

            //Prepare to insert old rows (note user column is UNIQUE so pretty simple scenario just try inserting all and duplicates will be rejected)
            ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
            Cursor oldcsr = olddb.query("user",null,null,null,null,null,null);
            newdb.beginTransaction();
            while (oldcsr.moveToNext()) {
                cv.clear();
                for (String columnname: oldcolumns) {
                    cv.put(columnname,oldcsr.getString(oldcsr.getColumnIndex(columnname)));
                }
                newdb.insert("user",null,cv);
            }
            newdb.setTransactionSuccessful();
            newdb.endTransaction();
            newdb.close();
            olddb.close();

            // Finally delete the renamed old database
            DBAssetHandler.clearForceBackups(context,DBNAME);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

    }
}
```

- Note that there is little bloat in the way of methods to add, delete an extract rows. However, it is a little overly complex in that it handles switching between versions to facilitate demonstration.

Lastly is an example activity that invokes utilises PEV2DBHelper, writing the schema and the rows from the table to the log.

The activity used is **MainActivity.java** and is :-

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    PEV2DBHelper mDBHlpr2; //DBHelper for example that retains user data

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        doPEV2(); // Test simple more complex scenario
    }


    private void doPEV2() {

        mDBHlpr2 = new PEV2DBHelper(this);
        SQLiteDatabase db = mDBHlpr2.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor csr = db.query("sqlite_master",null,null,null,null,null,null);
        DatabaseUtils.dumpCursor(csr);
        csr = db.query("user",null,null,null,null,null,null);
        DatabaseUtils.dumpCursor(csr);
        if (PEV2DBHelper.DBVERSION == 1) {
            addUserData(db);
            csr = db.query("user",null,null,null,null,null,null);
            DatabaseUtils.dumpCursor(csr);
        }
        csr.close();
        db.close();
    }

    /**
     * Add some user data for testing presevation of that data
     * @param db    the SQLitedatabase
     */
    private void addUserData(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put("user","mr new user");
        cv.put("password","a password");
        db.insert("user",null,cv);
    }
}
```

## Results

### 1. When first run with the DBVERSION as 1 (brand new App)

In this case the asset file **pev1.db** is copied from the assets folder the output is :-

```
2019-02-22 19:07:54.676 28670-28670/? D/DBFILEVERSION: Database File Version = -666666666
2019-02-22 19:07:54.677 28670-28670/? D/DBFILEVERSION: Asset Database File Version = 0
2019-02-22 19:07:54.677 28670-28670/? D/DBFILEVERSION: Asset Database File Version = 0
2019-02-22 19:07:54.677 28670-28670/? D/DBPATH: DB Path is /data/user/0/mjt.so54807516/databases/pev1.db
2019-02-22 19:07:54.677 28670-28670/? D/COPYDATABASE: Initiated Copy of the database file pev1.db from the assets folder.
2019-02-22 19:07:54.677 28670-28670/? D/COPYDATABASE: Asset file pev1.db found so attmepting to copy to /data/user/0/mjt.so54807516/databases/pev1.db
2019-02-22 19:07:54.677 28670-28670/? D/COPYDATABASE: Attempting copy of block 1 which has 4096 bytes.
2019-02-22 19:07:54.677 28670-28670/? D/COPYDATABASE: Attempting copy of block 2 which has 4096 bytes.
2019-02-22 19:07:54.677 28670-28670/? D/COPYDATABASE: Finished copying Database pev1.db from the assets folder, to  /data/user/0/mjt.so54807516/databases/pev1.db8192were copied, in 2 blocks of size 4096.
2019-02-22 19:07:54.678 28670-28670/? D/COPYDATABASE: All Streams have been flushed and closed.
2019-02-22 19:07:54.678 28670-28670/? D/DBPATH: DB Path is /data/user/0/mjt.so54807516/databases/pev1.db
2019-02-22 19:07:54.701 28670-28670/? I/System.out: >>>>> Dumping cursor android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor@71528f1
2019-02-22 19:07:54.701 28670-28670/? I/System.out: 0 {
2019-02-22 19:07:54.701 28670-28670/? I/System.out:    type=table
2019-02-22 19:07:54.701 28670-28670/? I/System.out:    name=user
2019-02-22 19:07:54.701 28670-28670/? I/System.out:    tbl_name=user
2019-02-22 19:07:54.702 28670-28670/? I/System.out:    rootpage=2
2019-02-22 19:07:54.702 28670-28670/? I/System.out:    sql=CREATE TABLE "user" (
2019-02-22 19:07:54.702 28670-28670/? I/System.out:   "_id" INTEGER NOT NULL,
2019-02-22 19:07:54.702 28670-28670/? I/System.out:   "user" TEXT,
2019-02-22 19:07:54.702 28670-28670/? I/System.out:   "password" TEXT,
2019-02-22 19:07:54.702 28670-28670/? I/System.out:   PRIMARY KEY ("_id")
2019-02-22 19:07:54.702 28670-28670/? I/System.out: )
2019-02-22 19:07:54.702 28670-28670/? I/System.out: }
2019-02-22 19:07:54.702 28670-28670/? I/System.out: 1 {
2019-02-22 19:07:54.702 28670-28670/? I/System.out:    type=table
2019-02-22 19:07:54.702 28670-28670/? I/System.out:    name=android_metadata
2019-02-22 19:07:54.702 28670-28670/? I/System.out:    tbl_name=android_metadata
2019-02-22 19:07:54.702 28670-28670/? I/System.out:    rootpage=3
2019-02-22 19:07:54.702 28670-28670/? I/System.out:    sql=CREATE TABLE android_metadata (locale TEXT)
2019-02-22 19:07:54.702 28670-28670/? I/System.out: }
2019-02-22 19:07:54.702 28670-28670/? I/System.out: <<<<<
2019-02-22 19:07:54.703 28670-28670/? I/System.out: >>>>> Dumping cursor android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor@1e20cd6
2019-02-22 19:07:54.703 28670-28670/? I/System.out: 0 {
2019-02-22 19:07:54.703 28670-28670/? I/System.out:    _id=1
2019-02-22 19:07:54.703 28670-28670/? I/System.out:    user=Fred
2019-02-22 19:07:54.703 28670-28670/? I/System.out:    password=fredpassword
2019-02-22 19:07:54.703 28670-28670/? I/System.out: }
2019-02-22 19:07:54.703 28670-28670/? I/System.out: 1 {
2019-02-22 19:07:54.703 28670-28670/? I/System.out:    _id=2
2019-02-22 19:07:54.703 28670-28670/? I/System.out:    user=Mary
2019-02-22 19:07:54.704 28670-28670/? I/System.out:    password=marypassword
2019-02-22 19:07:54.704 28670-28670/? I/System.out: }
2019-02-22 19:07:54.704 28670-28670/? I/System.out: <<<<<
2019-02-22 19:07:54.705 28670-28670/? I/System.out: >>>>> Dumping cursor android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor@acdb57
2019-02-22 19:07:54.705 28670-28670/? I/System.out: 0 {
2019-02-22 19:07:54.705 28670-28670/? I/System.out:    _id=1
2019-02-22 19:07:54.705 28670-28670/? I/System.out:    user=Fred
2019-02-22 19:07:54.705 28670-28670/? I/System.out:    password=fredpassword
2019-02-22 19:07:54.706 28670-28670/? I/System.out: }
2019-02-22 19:07:54.706 28670-28670/? I/System.out: 1 {
2019-02-22 19:07:54.706 28670-28670/? I/System.out:    _id=2
2019-02-22 19:07:54.706 28670-28670/? I/System.out:    user=Mary
2019-02-22 19:07:54.706 28670-28670/? I/System.out:    password=marypassword
2019-02-22 19:07:54.706 28670-28670/? I/System.out: }
2019-02-22 19:07:54.706 28670-28670/? I/System.out: 2 {
2019-02-22 19:07:54.706 28670-28670/? I/System.out:    _id=3
2019-02-22 19:07:54.706 28670-28670/? I/System.out:    user=mr new user
2019-02-22 19:07:54.706 28670-28670/? I/System.out:    password=a password
2019-02-22 19:07:54.706 28670-28670/? I/System.out: }
2019-02-22 19:07:54.706 28670-28670/? I/System.out: <<<<<
```

- -666666666 is the version as no file existed hence the attempt to get the version from the file returned the default value to indicate that the version could not be obtained.

### 2. Second run all the same EXCEPT the version number is 1.

```
2019-02-22 19:09:43.724 28730-28730/mjt.so54807516 D/DBFILEVERSION: Database File Version = 1
2019-02-22 19:09:43.724 28730-28730/mjt.so54807516 D/DBFILEVERSION: Asset Database File Version = 0
2019-02-22 19:09:43.724 28730-28730/mjt.so54807516 D/DBFILEVERSION: Asset Database File Version = 0
2019-02-22 19:09:43.725 28730-28730/mjt.so54807516 D/DBPATH: DB Path is /data/user/0/mjt.so54807516/databases/pev1.db
2019-02-22 19:09:43.725 28730-28730/mjt.so54807516 D/DBPATH: DB Path is /data/user/0/mjt.so54807516/databases/pev1.db
2019-02-22 19:09:43.729 28730-28730/mjt.so54807516 I/System.out: >>>>> 
..... etc
```

### 3. Next run after changing DBVERSION to 2

```
2019-02-22 19:13:49.157 28866-28866/mjt.so54807516 D/DBFILEVERSION: Database File Version = 1
2019-02-22 19:13:49.158 28866-28866/mjt.so54807516 D/DBFILEVERSION: Asset Database File Version = 0
2019-02-22 19:13:49.158 28866-28866/mjt.so54807516 D/DBFILEVERSION: Asset Database File Version = 0
2019-02-22 19:13:49.158 28866-28866/mjt.so54807516 D/DBPATH: DB Path is /data/user/0/mjt.so54807516/databases/pev1.db
2019-02-22 19:13:49.158 28866-28866/mjt.so54807516 D/DBPATH: DB Path is /data/user/0/mjt.so54807516/databases/pev1.db
2019-02-22 19:13:49.158 28866-28866/mjt.so54807516 D/COPYDATABASE: Initiated Copy of the database file pev1mod.db from the assets folder.
2019-02-22 19:13:49.159 28866-28866/mjt.so54807516 D/COPYDATABASE: Asset file pev1mod.db found so attmepting to copy to /data/user/0/mjt.so54807516/databases/pev1.db
2019-02-22 19:13:49.159 28866-28866/mjt.so54807516 D/COPYDATABASE: Attempting copy of block 1 which has 4096 bytes.
2019-02-22 19:13:49.159 28866-28866/mjt.so54807516 D/COPYDATABASE: Attempting copy of block 2 which has 4096 bytes.
2019-02-22 19:13:49.159 28866-28866/mjt.so54807516 D/COPYDATABASE: Attempting copy of block 3 which has 4096 bytes.
2019-02-22 19:13:49.159 28866-28866/mjt.so54807516 D/COPYDATABASE: Attempting copy of block 4 which has 4096 bytes.
2019-02-22 19:13:49.159 28866-28866/mjt.so54807516 D/COPYDATABASE: Finished copying Database pev1.db from the assets folder, to  /data/user/0/mjt.so54807516/databases/pev1.db16384were copied, in 4 blocks of size 4096.
2019-02-22 19:13:49.159 28866-28866/mjt.so54807516 D/COPYDATABASE: All Streams have been flushed and closed.
2019-02-22 19:13:49.186 28866-28866/mjt.so54807516 E/SQLiteDatabase: Error inserting password=fredpassword user=Fred
    android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException: UNIQUE constraint failed: user.user (code 2067 SQLITE_CONSTRAINT_UNIQUE)
        at 
    .........
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
2019-02-22 19:13:49.191 28866-28866/mjt.so54807516 E/SQLiteDatabase: Error inserting password=a password user=mr new user
    android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException: UNIQUE constraint failed: user.user (code 2067 SQLITE_CONSTRAINT_UNIQUE)
        at 
   .............
2019-02-22 19:13:49.209 28866-28866/mjt.so54807516 I/System.out: >>>>> Dumping cursor android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor@34252b0
2019-02-22 19:13:49.210 28866-28866/mjt.so54807516 I/System.out: 0 {
2019-02-22 19:13:49.210 28866-28866/mjt.so54807516 I/System.out:    type=table
2019-02-22 19:13:49.210 28866-28866/mjt.so54807516 I/System.out:    name=user
2019-02-22 19:13:49.210 28866-28866/mjt.so54807516 I/System.out:    tbl_name=user
2019-02-22 19:13:49.210 28866-28866/mjt.so54807516 I/System.out:    rootpage=2
2019-02-22 19:13:49.210 28866-28866/mjt.so54807516 I/System.out:    sql=CREATE TABLE "user" (
2019-02-22 19:13:49.210 28866-28866/mjt.so54807516 I/System.out:   "_id" INTEGER NOT NULL,
2019-02-22 19:13:49.210 28866-28866/mjt.so54807516 I/System.out:   "user" TEXT,
2019-02-22 19:13:49.210 28866-28866/mjt.so54807516 I/System.out:   "password" TEXT,
2019-02-22 19:13:49.210 28866-28866/mjt.so54807516 I/System.out:   "email" TEXT,
2019-02-22 19:13:49.210 28866-28866/mjt.so54807516 I/System.out:   PRIMARY KEY ("_id"),
2019-02-22 19:13:49.210 28866-28866/mjt.so54807516 I/System.out:   CONSTRAINT "user" UNIQUE ("user")
2019-02-22 19:13:49.211 28866-28866/mjt.so54807516 I/System.out: )
2019-02-22 19:13:49.211 28866-28866/mjt.so54807516 I/System.out: }
2019-02-22 19:13:49.211 28866-28866/mjt.so54807516 I/System.out: 1 {
2019-02-22 19:13:49.211 28866-28866/mjt.so54807516 I/System.out:    type=index
2019-02-22 19:13:49.211 28866-28866/mjt.so54807516 I/System.out:    name=sqlite_autoindex_user_1
2019-02-22 19:13:49.211 28866-28866/mjt.so54807516 I/System.out:    tbl_name=user
2019-02-22 19:13:49.211 28866-28866/mjt.so54807516 I/System.out:    rootpage=4
2019-02-22 19:13:49.211 28866-28866/mjt.so54807516 I/System.out:    sql=null
2019-02-22 19:13:49.211 28866-28866/mjt.so54807516 I/System.out: }
2019-02-22 19:13:49.211 28866-28866/mjt.so54807516 I/System.out: 2 {
2019-02-22 19:13:49.211 28866-28866/mjt.so54807516 I/System.out:    type=table
2019-02-22 19:13:49.211 28866-28866/mjt.so54807516 I/System.out:    name=android_metadata
2019-02-22 19:13:49.211 28866-28866/mjt.so54807516 I/System.out:    tbl_name=android_metadata
2019-02-22 19:13:49.211 28866-28866/mjt.so54807516 I/System.out:    rootpage=3
2019-02-22 19:13:49.211 28866-28866/mjt.so54807516 I/System.out:    sql=CREATE TABLE android_metadata (locale TEXT)
2019-02-22 19:13:49.212 28866-28866/mjt.so54807516 I/System.out: }
2019-02-22 19:13:49.212 28866-28866/mjt.so54807516 I/System.out: <<<<<
2019-02-22 19:13:49.212 28866-28866/mjt.so54807516 I/System.out: >>>>> Dumping cursor android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor@c8f0529
2019-02-22 19:13:49.213 28866-28866/mjt.so54807516 I/System.out: 0 {
2019-02-22 19:13:49.213 28866-28866/mjt.so54807516 I/System.out:    _id=1
2019-02-22 19:13:49.213 28866-28866/mjt.so54807516 I/System.out:    user=Fred
2019-02-22 19:13:49.213 28866-28866/mjt.so54807516 I/System.out:    password=fredpassword
2019-02-22 19:13:49.213 28866-28866/mjt.so54807516 I/System.out:    email=fred@email.com
2019-02-22 19:13:49.213 28866-28866/mjt.so54807516 I/System.out: }
2019-02-22 19:13:49.213 28866-28866/mjt.so54807516 I/System.out: 1 {
2019-02-22 19:13:49.213 28866-28866/mjt.so54807516 I/System.out:    _id=2
2019-02-22 19:13:49.213 28866-28866/mjt.so54807516 I/System.out:    
...... etc
```

Answer (score 0):

**Note this answer supplements the main answer**

If just introducing new data/schema without the need to preserve user data then the a simpler version of the database helper can be used, for example :-

**PVE1DBHelper.java**

```
/**
 * SIMPLE CASE EXAMPLE WHENEVER APP's DBVERSION is changed re-copy asset DB to db file
 */
public class PEV1DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public static final String DBNAME = "pev1.db";
    public static final int DBVERSION = 1; //<<<<<<<<<< increase and db file from assets will be re-copied
    Context mContext;

    public PEV1DBHelper(Context context) {

        super(context, DBNAME, null, DBVERSION);
        mContext = context;

        int dbversion = DBAssetHandler.getVersionFromDBFile(mContext,DBNAME);
        Log.d("DBFILEVERSION","Database File Version = " + String.valueOf(dbversion));

        // Alternative to onUpgrade
        // bypass issues with potential DB re-open already closed due to onUpgrade being passed SQLiteDatabase
        // i.e. done before any attempt to get open the database
        if (DBVERSION > dbversion & DBAssetHandler.checkDataBase(mContext,DBNAME)) {
            Log.d("UPGRADING","Re-copying database file from the assets file due to App DBVERSION change.");
            DBAssetHandler.copyDataBase(mContext,DBNAME,true);
            DBAssetHandler.clearForceBackups(mContext,DBNAME);
        }

        // Original copy from the assets folder
        if (!DBAssetHandler.checkDataBase(mContext,DBNAME)) {
            Log.d("INITIALDBCOPY","Copying database file from the assets file due to DB not existing.");
            DBAssetHandler.copyDataBase(mContext,DBNAME,true); // no need for true as existing should exist
            DBAssetHandler.clearForceBackups(mContext,DBNAME); // also no need for clearing backups as none
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    }
}
```

- Note the comments in the *Original copy from the assets folder* section i.e. just the single line `DBAssetHandler.copyDataBase(mContext,DBNAME,false);` could be used