# Android Sqlite onupgrade delete table from database

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I am using prepopulated database in my app and i have created two tables, Dictionary and Bookmark table .
Dictionary table has the data i want to show and the Bookmark table saves the data if the user marks something as Favourite.
What i want to do is when onupgrade method is called update the data in dictionary table and save the data in Bookmark table. Can anyone give me example to do that.

P.S. I don't have much experience with Sqlite

Comment: I will suggest to use ROOM database, which is an abstract layer of SQLite. 

Here you need to to write content provider. Simply you can do the CURD operation in the DAO.

Try it once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following is the code as used for the answer to a previous question (link below) amended to include a new method, namely **restoreTable** in **DatabaseAssetHandler.java**

The method will copy any table, as passed, from the backed-up database (made when copying a new database form the asset folder (as per the previous answer)). It does not include the complications of checking to see if the passed table exists.

It opens two SQLiteDatabase instances the new database and the old backed up database. Extracts all rows from the old database and inserts them into table with the same name in the new database.

This method, on it's own is :-

```
/**
 *
 * @param context   The context so that the respective package is used
 * @param dbname    The name of the database (the old will have -backup appended)
 * @param table     The table from which to copy the data
 */
public static void restoreTable(Context context, String dbname, String table) {
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    SQLiteDatabase dbnew = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(context.getDatabasePath(dbname).toString(), null,SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
    SQLiteDatabase dbold = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(context.getDatabasePath(dbname + backup).toString(),null,SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
    Cursor csr = dbold.query(table,null,null,null,null,null,null);
    dbnew.beginTransaction();
    while (csr.moveToNext()) {
        cv.clear();
        int offset = 0;
        for (String column: csr.getColumnNames()) {
            switch (csr.getType(offset++)){
                case Cursor.FIELD_TYPE_NULL:
                    break;
                case Cursor.FIELD_TYPE_INTEGER:
                    cv.put(column,csr.getLong(csr.getColumnIndex(column)));
                    break;
                case Cursor.FIELD_TYPE_FLOAT:
                    cv.put(column,csr.getFloat(csr.getColumnIndex(column)));
                    break;
                case Cursor.FIELD_TYPE_STRING:
                    cv.put(column,csr.getString(csr.getColumnIndex(column)));
                    break;
                case Cursor.FIELD_TYPE_BLOB:
                    cv.put(column,csr.getBlob(csr.getColumnIndex(column)));
            }
        }
        dbnew.insert(DatabaseHelper.TABLE_BOOKMARK,null,cv);
    }
    dbnew.setTransactionSuccessful();
    dbnew.endTransaction();
    csr.close();
    dbnew.close();
    dbold.close();
}
```

- This method would need to be added to the DatabaseAssetHandler code [from the previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55711282/on-upgrade-method-not-getting-called-in-android-sqlite).

To facilitate testing of the above a few changes have been made to **DatabaseHelper.java**, this is now :-

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private  static final String DB_NAME = "dictionary.db";
    private static final int DB_VERSION = 2;
    public static final String TABLE_DICTIONARY = "dictionary";
    public static final String TABLE_BOOKMARK= "bookmark";
    public static final String COL_ID = "id";
    public static final String COL_WORD = "word";
    public static final String COL_DEFINITION = "definition";
    public static final String COL_WORID = "wordid"; //<<<<<<<<<< ADDED
    public Context mcontext;
    public SQLiteDatabase mDatabase;

    public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DB_NAME, null, DB_VERSION);
        this.mcontext = context;
        Log.d("DBVERSION","The Database Version (as hard coded) is " + String.valueOf(DB_VERSION));

        int dbversion = DatabaseAssetHandler.getVersionFromDBFile(context,DB_NAME);
        Log.d("DBVERSION","The Database Version (as per the database file) is " + String.valueOf(dbversion));

        // Copy the Database if no database exists
        if (!DatabaseAssetHandler.checkDataBase(context,DB_NAME)) {
            DatabaseAssetHandler.copyDataBase(context,DB_NAME,true,DB_VERSION);
        } else {
            if (DB_VERSION > dbversion && DatabaseAssetHandler.checkDataBase(context, DB_NAME)) {
                DatabaseAssetHandler.copyDataBase(context, DB_NAME, true, DB_VERSION);
                DatabaseAssetHandler.restoreTable(context,DB_NAME,TABLE_BOOKMARK); //<<<<<<<<<< ADDED for keeping the BOOKMARKS
                DatabaseAssetHandler.clearForceBackups(context, DB_NAME); // Clear the backups
            }
        }
        mDatabase = this.getWritableDatabase();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    }

    public void openDatabase() throws SQLException {
        mDatabase = this.getWritableDatabase();
    }

    //<<<<<<<<<< ADDED to allow some bookmarks to be added
    public long addBookMark(long wordid) {
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(DatabaseHelper.COL_WORID,wordid);
        return mDatabase.insert(DatabaseHelper.TABLE_BOOKMARK,null,cv);
    }

    // Added to retrieve the database name (could make DB_NAME public)
    public String getDBNAME() {
        return this.DB_NAME;
    }

    //ADDED to dump the bookmarks along with the related word and definition
    public void logBookmarksWithWord() {

        String table_part = TABLE_BOOKMARK +
                " JOIN " + TABLE_DICTIONARY +
                " ON " + COL_WORID +
                " = " + TABLE_DICTIONARY + "." + COL_ID;
        String[] columns = new String[]{TABLE_BOOKMARK + "." + COL_ID, COL_WORID, COL_WORD, COL_DEFINITION};
        Cursor csr = mDatabase.query(table_part,columns,null,null,null,null,COL_WORD);
        DatabaseUtils.dumpCursor(csr);
        csr.close();
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void close() {
        if (mDatabase != null)
            mDatabase.close();
        super.close();
    }
}
```

The same 2 versions of databases were used as per the previous answer. However, the **invoking activity** had additional code added to a) add some bookmarks when the the DB is copied from the assets folder, and to b) always output the bookmarks to the log (to show they are retained).

The **invoking activity** used is :-

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    DatabaseHelper mDBHlpr;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mDBHlpr = new DatabaseHelper(this);
        Cursor csr = mDBHlpr.getWritableDatabase().query(
                DatabaseHelper.TABLE_DICTIONARY,
                null,null,null,null,null,null
        );
        DatabaseUtils.dumpCursor(csr);
        //<<<<<<<<<< ADDED CODE
        // Add a couple of bookmarks only if database is copied for testing
        if (DatabaseUtils.queryNumEntries(mDBHlpr.mDatabase,DatabaseHelper.TABLE_BOOKMARK) < 1) {
            mDBHlpr.addBookMark(1);
            mDBHlpr.addBookMark(3);
        }
        // Always dump the bookmarks to the log
        mDBHlpr.logBookmarksWithWord();
        //<<<<<<<<<< END OF ADDED CODE
        csr.close();
    }
}
```

- Note the assumption has been made that the bookmarks table, albeit it empty (it needn't be) exists in the pre-existing database. If it doesn't exist then this would fail.

## Testing/Results

### Run 1

This run is for a new installation of the App and DB_VERSION is 1 (so the pre-exisiting database (initial version) is copied from the assets folder).

```
04-22 18:06:17.603 8734-8734/? D/DBVERSION: The Database Version (as hard coded) is 1
04-22 18:06:17.603 8734-8734/? D/DBVERSION: The Database Version (as per the database file) is -666666666
04-22 18:06:17.603 8734-8734/? D/DBPATH: DB Path is /data/user/0/m.example.so55711282dictionary/databases/dictionary.db
04-22 18:06:17.603 8734-8734/? D/COPYDATABASE: Initiated Copy of the database file dictionary.db from the assets folder.
04-22 18:06:17.603 8734-8734/? D/COPYDATABASE: Asset file dictionary.db found so attmepting to copy to /data/user/0/m.example.so55711282dictionary/databases/dictionary.db
04-22 18:06:17.604 8734-8734/? D/COPYDATABASE: Attempting copy of block 1 which has 4096 bytes.
04-22 18:06:17.604 8734-8734/? D/COPYDATABASE: Attempting copy of block 2 which has 4096 bytes.
04-22 18:06:17.604 8734-8734/? D/COPYDATABASE: Attempting copy of block 3 which has 4096 bytes.
04-22 18:06:17.604 8734-8734/? D/COPYDATABASE: Finished copying Database dictionary.db from the assets folder, to  /data/user/0/m.example.so55711282dictionary/databases/dictionary.db12288were copied, in 3 blocks of size 4096.
04-22 18:06:17.604 8734-8734/? D/COPYDATABASE: All Streams have been flushed and closed.
04-22 18:06:17.625 8734-8734/? I/System.out: >>>>> Dumping cursor android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor@3396ef
04-22 18:06:17.625 8734-8734/? I/System.out: 0 {
04-22 18:06:17.625 8734-8734/? I/System.out:    id=1
04-22 18:06:17.625 8734-8734/? I/System.out:    word=Apple
04-22 18:06:17.625 8734-8734/? I/System.out:    definition=Thing that drops from an Apple Tree.
04-22 18:06:17.625 8734-8734/? I/System.out: }
04-22 18:06:17.625 8734-8734/? I/System.out: 1 {
04-22 18:06:17.625 8734-8734/? I/System.out:    id=2
04-22 18:06:17.625 8734-8734/? I/System.out:    word=Bucket
04-22 18:06:17.625 8734-8734/? I/System.out:    definition=Hand held container with carrying hanlde.
04-22 18:06:17.625 8734-8734/? I/System.out: }
04-22 18:06:17.625 8734-8734/? I/System.out: <<<<<


04-22 18:06:17.631 8734-8734/? D/BOOKMARKDUMP: Dumping the bookmarks table to the log.
04-22 18:06:17.631 8734-8734/? I/System.out: >>>>> Dumping cursor android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor@9ce45fc
04-22 18:06:17.631 8734-8734/? I/System.out: 0 {
04-22 18:06:17.631 8734-8734/? I/System.out:    id=1
04-22 18:06:17.631 8734-8734/? I/System.out:    wordid=1
04-22 18:06:17.631 8734-8734/? I/System.out:    word=Apple
04-22 18:06:17.631 8734-8734/? I/System.out:    definition=Thing that drops from an Apple Tree.
04-22 18:06:17.631 8734-8734/? I/System.out: }
04-22 18:06:17.631 8734-8734/? I/System.out: <<<<<
```

### Run 2

Simply run again no changes, so no copy bookmark exists.

```
04-22 18:40:56.304 8858-8858/m.example.so55711282dictionary D/DBVERSION: The Database Version (as hard coded) is 1
04-22 18:40:56.304 8858-8858/m.example.so55711282dictionary D/DBVERSION: The Database Version (as per the database file) is 1
04-22 18:40:56.304 8858-8858/m.example.so55711282dictionary D/DBPATH: DB Path is /data/user/0/m.example.so55711282dictionary/databases/dictionary.db
04-22 18:40:56.308 8858-8858/m.example.so55711282dictionary I/System.out: >>>>> Dumping cursor android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor@11697ce
04-22 18:40:56.308 8858-8858/m.example.so55711282dictionary I/System.out: 0 {
04-22 18:40:56.308 8858-8858/m.example.so55711282dictionary I/System.out:    id=1
04-22 18:40:56.308 8858-8858/m.example.so55711282dictionary I/System.out:    word=Apple
04-22 18:40:56.308 8858-8858/m.example.so55711282dictionary I/System.out:    definition=Thing that drops from an Apple Tree.
04-22 18:40:56.308 8858-8858/m.example.so55711282dictionary I/System.out: }
04-22 18:40:56.308 8858-8858/m.example.so55711282dictionary I/System.out: 1 {
04-22 18:40:56.309 8858-8858/m.example.so55711282dictionary I/System.out:    id=2
04-22 18:40:56.309 8858-8858/m.example.so55711282dictionary I/System.out:    word=Bucket
04-22 18:40:56.309 8858-8858/m.example.so55711282dictionary I/System.out:    definition=Hand held container with carrying hanlde.
04-22 18:40:56.309 8858-8858/m.example.so55711282dictionary I/System.out: }
04-22 18:40:56.309 8858-8858/m.example.so55711282dictionary I/System.out: <<<<<
04-22 18:40:56.309 8858-8858/m.example.so55711282dictionary D/BOOKMARKDUMP: Dumping the bookmarks table to the log.
04-22 18:40:56.309 8858-8858/m.example.so55711282dictionary I/System.out: >>>>> Dumping cursor android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor@3396ef
04-22 18:40:56.309 8858-8858/m.example.so55711282dictionary I/System.out: 0 {
04-22 18:40:56.309 8858-8858/m.example.so55711282dictionary I/System.out:    id=1
04-22 18:40:56.309 8858-8858/m.example.so55711282dictionary I/System.out:    wordid=1
04-22 18:40:56.309 8858-8858/m.example.so55711282dictionary I/System.out:    word=Apple
04-22 18:40:56.309 8858-8858/m.example.so55711282dictionary I/System.out:    definition=Thing that drops from an Apple Tree.
04-22 18:40:56.309 8858-8858/m.example.so55711282dictionary I/System.out: }
04-22 18:40:56.309 8858-8858/m.example.so55711282dictionary I/System.out: <<<<<
```

### Run 3

New version of database introduced DB_VERSION changed to 2 (some more words so the bookmark for word with the id 3 has a related word). New version of DB copied. The two bookmarks have been retained.

```
04-22 18:44:58.749 8975-8975/? D/DBVERSION: The Database Version (as hard coded) is 2
04-22 18:44:58.749 8975-8975/? D/DBVERSION: The Database Version (as per the database file) is 1
04-22 18:44:58.749 8975-8975/? D/DBPATH: DB Path is /data/user/0/m.example.so55711282dictionary/databases/dictionary.db
04-22 18:44:58.749 8975-8975/? D/DBPATH: DB Path is /data/user/0/m.example.so55711282dictionary/databases/dictionary.db
04-22 18:44:58.750 8975-8975/? D/COPYDATABASE: Initiated Copy of the database file dictionary.db from the assets folder.
04-22 18:44:58.750 8975-8975/? D/COPYDATABASE: Asset file dictionary.db found so attmepting to copy to /data/user/0/m.example.so55711282dictionary/databases/dictionary.db
04-22 18:44:58.750 8975-8975/? D/COPYDATABASE: Attempting copy of block 1 which has 4096 bytes.
04-22 18:44:58.750 8975-8975/? D/COPYDATABASE: Attempting copy of block 2 which has 4096 bytes.
04-22 18:44:58.750 8975-8975/? D/COPYDATABASE: Attempting copy of block 3 which has 4096 bytes.
04-22 18:44:58.750 8975-8975/? D/COPYDATABASE: Finished copying Database dictionary.db from the assets folder, to  /data/user/0/m.example.so55711282dictionary/databases/dictionary.db12288were copied, in 3 blocks of size 4096.
04-22 18:44:58.750 8975-8975/? D/COPYDATABASE: All Streams have been flushed and closed.
04-22 18:44:58.783 8975-8975/? I/System.out: >>>>> Dumping cursor android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor@10862da
04-22 18:44:58.784 8975-8975/? I/System.out: 0 {
04-22 18:44:58.784 8975-8975/? I/System.out:    id=1
04-22 18:44:58.784 8975-8975/? I/System.out:    word=Apple
04-22 18:44:58.784 8975-8975/? I/System.out:    definition=Thing that drops from an Apple Tree.
04-22 18:44:58.784 8975-8975/? I/System.out: }
04-22 18:44:58.784 8975-8975/? I/System.out: 1 {
04-22 18:44:58.784 8975-8975/? I/System.out:    id=2
04-22 18:44:58.784 8975-8975/? I/System.out:    word=Bucket
04-22 18:44:58.784 8975-8975/? I/System.out:    definition=Hand held container with carrying hanlde.
04-22 18:44:58.784 8975-8975/? I/System.out: }
04-22 18:44:58.784 8975-8975/? I/System.out: 2 {
04-22 18:44:58.784 8975-8975/? I/System.out:    id=3
04-22 18:44:58.784 8975-8975/? I/System.out:    word=Yelllow
04-22 18:44:58.784 8975-8975/? I/System.out:    definition=A colour.
04-22 18:44:58.784 8975-8975/? I/System.out: }
04-22 18:44:58.784 8975-8975/? I/System.out: 3 {
04-22 18:44:58.784 8975-8975/? I/System.out:    id=4
04-22 18:44:58.784 8975-8975/? I/System.out:    word=Zebra
04-22 18:44:58.784 8975-8975/? I/System.out:    definition=A balck and white, horse-like animal.
04-22 18:44:58.784 8975-8975/? I/System.out: }
04-22 18:44:58.784 8975-8975/? I/System.out: <<<<<
04-22 18:44:58.784 8975-8975/? D/BOOKMARKDUMP: Dumping the bookmarks table to the log.
04-22 18:44:58.785 8975-8975/? I/System.out: >>>>> Dumping cursor android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor@d4cb30b
04-22 18:44:58.785 8975-8975/? I/System.out: 0 {
04-22 18:44:58.785 8975-8975/? I/System.out:    id=1
04-22 18:44:58.785 8975-8975/? I/System.out:    wordid=1
04-22 18:44:58.785 8975-8975/? I/System.out:    word=Apple
04-22 18:44:58.785 8975-8975/? I/System.out:    definition=Thing that drops from an Apple Tree.
04-22 18:44:58.785 8975-8975/? I/System.out: }
04-22 18:44:58.785 8975-8975/? I/System.out: 1 {
04-22 18:44:58.785 8975-8975/? I/System.out:    id=2
04-22 18:44:58.785 8975-8975/? I/System.out:    wordid=3
04-22 18:44:58.785 8975-8975/? I/System.out:    word=Yelllow
04-22 18:44:58.785 8975-8975/? I/System.out:    definition=A colour.
04-22 18:44:58.785 8975-8975/? I/System.out: }
04-22 18:44:58.785 8975-8975/? I/System.out: <<<<<
```

### RUN 4

Nothing changed, so no DB copy bookmarks still retained.

```
04-22 18:47:19.300 9047-9047/m.example.so55711282dictionary D/DBVERSION: The Database Version (as hard coded) is 2
04-22 18:47:19.300 9047-9047/m.example.so55711282dictionary D/DBVERSION: The Database Version (as per the database file) is 2
04-22 18:47:19.300 9047-9047/m.example.so55711282dictionary D/DBPATH: DB Path is /data/user/0/m.example.so55711282dictionary/databases/dictionary.db
04-22 18:47:19.302 9047-9047/m.example.so55711282dictionary I/System.out: >>>>> Dumping cursor android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor@11697ce
04-22 18:47:19.302 9047-9047/m.example.so55711282dictionary I/System.out: 0 {
04-22 18:47:19.302 9047-9047/m.example.so55711282dictionary I/System.out:    id=1
04-22 18:47:19.302 9047-9047/m.example.so55711282dictionary I/System.out:    word=Apple
04-22 18:47:19.302 9047-9047/m.example.so55711282dictionary I/System.out:    definition=Thing that drops from an Apple Tree.
04-22 18:47:19.303 9047-9047/m.example.so55711282dictionary I/System.out: }
04-22 18:47:19.303 9047-9047/m.example.so55711282dictionary I/System.out: 1 {
04-22 18:47:19.303 9047-9047/m.example.so55711282dictionary I/System.out:    id=2
04-22 18:47:19.303 9047-9047/m.example.so55711282dictionary I/System.out:    word=Bucket
04-22 18:47:19.303 9047-9047/m.example.so55711282dictionary I/System.out:    definition=Hand held container with carrying hanlde.
04-22 18:47:19.303 9047-9047/m.example.so55711282dictionary I/System.out: }
04-22 18:47:19.303 9047-9047/m.example.so55711282dictionary I/System.out: 2 {
04-22 18:47:19.303 9047-9047/m.example.so55711282dictionary I/System.out:    id=3
04-22 18:47:19.303 9047-9047/m.example.so55711282dictionary I/System.out:    word=Yelllow
04-22 18:47:19.303 9047-9047/m.example.so55711282dictionary I/System.out:    definition=A colour.
04-22 18:47:19.303 9047-9047/m.example.so55711282dictionary I/System.out: }
04-22 18:47:19.303 9047-9047/m.example.so55711282dictionary I/System.out: 3 {
04-22 18:47:19.303 9047-9047/m.example.so55711282dictionary I/System.out:    id=4
04-22 18:47:19.303 9047-9047/m.example.so55711282dictionary I/System.out:    word=Zebra
04-22 18:47:19.303 9047-9047/m.example.so55711282dictionary I/System.out:    definition=A balck and white, horse-like animal.
04-22 18:47:19.303 9047-9047/m.example.so55711282dictionary I/System.out: }
04-22 18:47:19.303 9047-9047/m.example.so55711282dictionary I/System.out: <<<<<
04-22 18:47:19.303 9047-9047/m.example.so55711282dictionary D/BOOKMARKDUMP: Dumping the bookmarks table to the log.
04-22 18:47:19.303 9047-9047/m.example.so55711282dictionary I/System.out: >>>>> Dumping cursor android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor@3396ef
04-22 18:47:19.303 9047-9047/m.example.so55711282dictionary I/System.out: 0 {
04-22 18:47:19.303 9047-9047/m.example.so55711282dictionary I/System.out:    id=1
04-22 18:47:19.303 9047-9047/m.example.so55711282dictionary I/System.out:    wordid=1
04-22 18:47:19.303 9047-9047/m.example.so55711282dictionary I/System.out:    word=Apple
04-22 18:47:19.303 9047-9047/m.example.so55711282dictionary I/System.out:    definition=Thing that drops from an Apple Tree.
04-22 18:47:19.303 9047-9047/m.example.so55711282dictionary I/System.out: }
04-22 18:47:19.303 9047-9047/m.example.so55711282dictionary I/System.out: 1 {
04-22 18:47:19.303 9047-9047/m.example.so55711282dictionary I/System.out:    id=2
04-22 18:47:19.303 9047-9047/m.example.so55711282dictionary I/System.out:    wordid=3
04-22 18:47:19.303 9047-9047/m.example.so55711282dictionary I/System.out:    word=Yelllow
04-22 18:47:19.303 9047-9047/m.example.so55711282dictionary I/System.out:    definition=A colour.
04-22 18:47:19.303 9047-9047/m.example.so55711282dictionary I/System.out: }
04-22 18:47:19.303 9047-9047/m.example.so55711282dictionary I/System.out: <<<<<
```

### RUN 5

App uninstalled. New version used.Bookmarks added as new DB BUT version is latest i.e. 2

```
04-22 18:50:55.297 9243-9243/m.example.so55711282dictionary D/DBVERSION: The Database Version (as hard coded) is 2
04-22 18:50:55.297 9243-9243/m.example.so55711282dictionary D/DBVERSION: The Database Version (as per the database file) is -666666666
04-22 18:50:55.297 9243-9243/m.example.so55711282dictionary D/DBPATH: DB Path is /data/user/0/m.example.so55711282dictionary/databases/dictionary.db
04-22 18:50:55.297 9243-9243/m.example.so55711282dictionary D/COPYDATABASE: Initiated Copy of the database file dictionary.db from the assets folder.
04-22 18:50:55.297 9243-9243/m.example.so55711282dictionary D/COPYDATABASE: Asset file dictionary.db found so attmepting to copy to /data/user/0/m.example.so55711282dictionary/databases/dictionary.db
04-22 18:50:55.297 9243-9243/m.example.so55711282dictionary D/COPYDATABASE: Attempting copy of block 1 which has 4096 bytes.
04-22 18:50:55.298 9243-9243/m.example.so55711282dictionary D/COPYDATABASE: Attempting copy of block 2 which has 4096 bytes.
04-22 18:50:55.298 9243-9243/m.example.so55711282dictionary D/COPYDATABASE: Attempting copy of block 3 which has 4096 bytes.
04-22 18:50:55.298 9243-9243/m.example.so55711282dictionary D/COPYDATABASE: Finished copying Database dictionary.db from the assets folder, to  /data/user/0/m.example.so55711282dictionary/databases/dictionary.db12288were copied, in 3 blocks of size 4096.
04-22 18:50:55.298 9243-9243/m.example.so55711282dictionary D/COPYDATABASE: All Streams have been flushed and closed.
04-22 18:50:55.320 9243-9243/m.example.so55711282dictionary I/System.out: >>>>> Dumping cursor android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor@3396ef
04-22 18:50:55.320 9243-9243/m.example.so55711282dictionary I/System.out: 0 {
04-22 18:50:55.320 9243-9243/m.example.so55711282dictionary I/System.out:    id=1
04-22 18:50:55.320 9243-9243/m.example.so55711282dictionary I/System.out:    word=Apple
04-22 18:50:55.320 9243-9243/m.example.so55711282dictionary I/System.out:    definition=Thing that drops from an Apple Tree.
04-22 18:50:55.320 9243-9243/m.example.so55711282dictionary I/System.out: }
04-22 18:50:55.320 9243-9243/m.example.so55711282dictionary I/System.out: 1 {
04-22 18:50:55.320 9243-9243/m.example.so55711282dictionary I/System.out:    id=2
04-22 18:50:55.320 9243-9243/m.example.so55711282dictionary I/System.out:    word=Bucket
04-22 18:50:55.321 9243-9243/m.example.so55711282dictionary I/System.out:    definition=Hand held container with carrying hanlde.
04-22 18:50:55.321 9243-9243/m.example.so55711282dictionary I/System.out: }
04-22 18:50:55.321 9243-9243/m.example.so55711282dictionary I/System.out: 2 {
04-22 18:50:55.321 9243-9243/m.example.so55711282dictionary I/System.out:    id=3
04-22 18:50:55.321 9243-9243/m.example.so55711282dictionary I/System.out:    word=Yelllow
04-22 18:50:55.321 9243-9243/m.example.so55711282dictionary I/System.out:    definition=A colour.
04-22 18:50:55.321 9243-9243/m.example.so55711282dictionary I/System.out: }
04-22 18:50:55.321 9243-9243/m.example.so55711282dictionary I/System.out: 3 {
04-22 18:50:55.321 9243-9243/m.example.so55711282dictionary I/System.out:    id=4
04-22 18:50:55.321 9243-9243/m.example.so55711282dictionary I/System.out:    word=Zebra
04-22 18:50:55.321 9243-9243/m.example.so55711282dictionary I/System.out:    definition=A balck and white, horse-like animal.
04-22 18:50:55.321 9243-9243/m.example.so55711282dictionary I/System.out: }
04-22 18:50:55.321 9243-9243/m.example.so55711282dictionary I/System.out: <<<<<
04-22 18:50:55.328 9243-9243/m.example.so55711282dictionary D/BOOKMARKDUMP: Dumping the bookmarks table to the log.
04-22 18:50:55.328 9243-9243/m.example.so55711282dictionary I/System.out: >>>>> Dumping cursor android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor@9ce45fc
04-22 18:50:55.328 9243-9243/m.example.so55711282dictionary I/System.out: 0 {
04-22 18:50:55.328 9243-9243/m.example.so55711282dictionary I/System.out:    id=1
04-22 18:50:55.328 9243-9243/m.example.so55711282dictionary I/System.out:    wordid=1
04-22 18:50:55.328 9243-9243/m.example.so55711282dictionary I/System.out:    word=Apple
04-22 18:50:55.328 9243-9243/m.example.so55711282dictionary I/System.out:    definition=Thing that drops from an Apple Tree.
04-22 18:50:55.328 9243-9243/m.example.so55711282dictionary I/System.out: }
04-22 18:50:55.328 9243-9243/m.example.so55711282dictionary I/System.out: 1 {
04-22 18:50:55.328 9243-9243/m.example.so55711282dictionary I/System.out:    id=2
04-22 18:50:55.328 9243-9243/m.example.so55711282dictionary I/System.out:    wordid=3
04-22 18:50:55.328 9243-9243/m.example.so55711282dictionary I/System.out:    word=Yelllow
04-22 18:50:55.328 9243-9243/m.example.so55711282dictionary I/System.out:    definition=A colour.
04-22 18:50:55.328 9243-9243/m.example.so55711282dictionary I/System.out: }
04-22 18:50:55.328 9243-9243/m.example.so55711282dictionary I/System.out: <<<<<
```

Comment: I tried your code on a Real device with Android 8. I get this error when I increment database version and Rerun the app https://ibb.co/BGQhH6m

Comment: A google search on [failed to commit install session](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42687607/application-installation-failed-in-android-studio/42695197#42695197) should help.

Answer (score 0):

put your task you have to do in onUpgrade(). This method will be called only when you upgrades your app. (ie. upgrading version number with the upgrading database version.)