# Android Sqlite App crashes in Android pie and above Gives SQLiteDiskIOException (code 522)

Tags: android, android-activity, android-sqlite, sqliteopenhelper

I'm trying to backup tables from my database when onupgrade method is called. I' m using the solution provided here  [Android Sqlite onupgrade delete table from database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55789395/android-sqlite-onupgrade-delete-table-from-database) .
It works fine on Android 8 but on Android 9 and above it crashes.

Here is the Method.

```
public static void restoreTable(Context context, String dbName, String table) {
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    SQLiteDatabase dbNew = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(context.getDatabasePath(dbName).toString(), null,SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
    SQLiteDatabase dbOld = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(context.getDatabasePath(dbName + backup).toString(),null,SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
    Cursor csr = dbOld.query(table,null,null,null,null,null,null);
    dbNew.beginTransaction();
    while (csr.moveToNext()) {
        cv.clear();
        int offset = 0;
        for (String column: csr.getColumnNames()) {
            switch (csr.getType(offset++)){
                case Cursor.FIELD_TYPE_NULL:
                    break;
                case Cursor.FIELD_TYPE_INTEGER:
                    cv.put(column,csr.getLong(csr.getColumnIndex(column)));
                    break;
                case Cursor.FIELD_TYPE_FLOAT:
                    cv.put(column,csr.getFloat(csr.getColumnIndex(column)));
                    break;
                case Cursor.FIELD_TYPE_STRING:
                    cv.put(column,csr.getString(csr.getColumnIndex(column)));
                    break;
                case Cursor.FIELD_TYPE_BLOB:
                    cv.put(column,csr.getBlob(csr.getColumnIndex(column)));
            }
        }
        dbNew.insert(DatabaseHelper.TABLE_BOOKMARK,null,cv);
    }
    dbNew.setTransactionSuccessful();
    dbNew.endTransaction();
    csr.close();
    dbNew.close();
    dbOld.close();
}
```

And here is the Log.

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.elytelabs.literarytermsdictionary/com.elytelabs.literarytermsdictionary.MainActivity}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: bookmark (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT * FROM bookmark
#################################################################
Error Code : 1 (SQLITE_ERROR)
Caused By : SQL(query) error or missing database.
    (no such table: bookmark (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT * FROM bookmark)
#################################################################
       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2957)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3032)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source)
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1696)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6944)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:327)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1374)
Caused by android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: bookmark (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT * FROM bookmark
#################################################################
Error Code : 1 (SQLITE_ERROR)
Caused By : SQL(query) error or missing database.
    (no such table: bookmark (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT * FROM bookmark)
#################################################################
       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(SQLiteConnection.java)
       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:1096)
       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:661)
       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:59)
       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.<init>(SQLiteQuery.java:37)
       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:44)
       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1746)
       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.queryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1593)
       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.query(SQLiteDatabase.java:1464)
       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.query(SQLiteDatabase.java:1632)
       at com.elytelabs.literarytermsdictionary.database.DatabaseHandler.restoreTable(DatabaseHandler.java:240)
       at com.elytelabs.literarytermsdictionary.database.DatabaseHelper.<init>(DatabaseHelper.java:34)
       at com.elytelabs.literarytermsdictionary.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:72)
       at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7183)
       at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1220)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2910)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3032)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source)
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1696)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6944)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:327)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1374)
```

Comment: Where is the database located on the filesystem?

Comment: You might be running into this: https://developer.android.com/preview/privacy/scoped-storage Can you verify it still happens on Android P if you lower the targetSdkVersion to Android P?

Comment: what is `DatabaseHandler.java` line `238` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The message indicates that the file (the backup at a guess) has been truncated. As per

> (522) SQLITE_IOERR_SHORT_READ
>
> The SQLITE_IOERR_SHORT_READ error code is an extended error code for 
>   SQLITE_IOERR indicating that a read attempt in the VFS layer was
>   unable to obtain as many bytes as was requested. This might be due to
>   a truncated file.

[Result and Error Codes](https://www.sqlite.org/rescode.html)

I suspect that your issue is related to Android 9 defaulting to using WAL ([Write-Ahead Logging](https://www.sqlite.org/wal.html) rather the journal mode). This results in two additional files (database file suffixed with -shm and -wal). These contain uncommitted transactions.

You likely either need to fully checkpoint the database before backing up or you need to backup the -wal and -shm files.

Alternately it may be that you are saving the file from the SQLite Management Tool, when there are still transactions awaiting to be committed. As such I suggest that you always close the tool and then re-open the tool and then copy the file. I'd also suggest that you check to see if the -wal and -shm files exist and if the length of the -wal file  is greater than 0 (if greater than 0 then the -wal will have outstanding transactions to be comitted). Running `PRAGMA wal_checkpoint(TRUNCATE)` followed by `PRAGMA wal_checkpoint` (you'd be looking for the 2nd and 3rd numbers to match in the first result and for them to both be 0 in the 2nd result).

Alternately you could disable WAL using the SQliteDatabase [disableWriteAheadLogging](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase#disableWriteAheadLogging()) method.

This is a method I have used to checkpoint the database before backing up (this handle WAl and JORUNAL mode) :-

```
private void checkpointIfWALEnabled(Context context) {
    final String TAG = "WALCHKPNT";
    Cursor csr;
    int wal_busy = -99, wal_log = -99, wal_checkpointed = -99;
    SQLiteDatabase db = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(context.getDatabasePath(DBConstants.DATABASE_NAME).getPath(),null,SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
    csr = db.rawQuery("PRAGMA journal_mode",null);
    if (csr.moveToFirst()) {
        String mode = csr.getString(0);
        //Log.d(TAG, "Mode is " + mode);
        if (mode.toLowerCase().equals("wal")) {
            csr = db.rawQuery("PRAGMA wal_checkpoint",null);
            if (csr.moveToFirst()) {
                wal_busy = csr.getInt(0);
                wal_log = csr.getInt(1);
                wal_checkpointed = csr.getInt(2);
            }
            //Log.d(TAG,"Checkpoint pre checkpointing Busy = " + String.valueOf(wal_busy) + " LOG = " + String.valueOf(wal_log) + " CHECKPOINTED = " + String.valueOf(wal_checkpointed) );
            csr = db.rawQuery("PRAGMA wal_checkpoint(TRUNCATE)",null);
            csr.getCount();
            csr = db.rawQuery("PRAGMA wal_checkpoint",null);
            if (csr.moveToFirst()) {
                wal_busy = csr.getInt(0);
                wal_log = csr.getInt(1);
                wal_checkpointed = csr.getInt(2);
            }
            //Log.d(TAG,"Checkpoint post checkpointing Busy = " + String.valueOf(wal_busy) + " LOG = " + String.valueOf(wal_log) + " CHECKPOINTED = " + String.valueOf(wal_checkpointed) );
        }
    }
    csr.close();
    db.close();
}
```

I've re-written the DatabaseAssetHandler (as used in the link) class to include the above checkpointIfWALEnabled method and also to specifically set the version number as it doesn't appear to do this (and would re-copy the db from the assets).

This does require that the calls to require the version number to be passed.

The new DatabaseAssetHandler class is :-

```
public class DatabaseAssetHandler {

    static final String[] tempfiles = new String[]{"-journal","-wal","-shm"}; // temporary files to rename
    public static final String backup = "-backup"; //value to be appended to file name when renaming (psuedo delete)
    public static final  int OUCH = -666666666;

    /**
     * Check if the database already exists. NOTE will create the databases folder is it doesn't exist
     * @return true if it exists, false if it doesn't
     */
    public static boolean checkDataBase(Context context, String dbname) {

        File db = new File(context.getDatabasePath(dbname).getPath()); //Get the file name of the database
        Log.d("DBPATH","DB Path is " + db.getPath()); //TODO remove if publish App
        if (db.exists()) return true; // If it exists then return doing nothing

        // Get the parent (directory in which the database file would be)
        File dbdir = db.getParentFile();
        // If the directory does not exits then make the directory (and higher level directories)
        if (!dbdir.exists()) {
            db.getParentFile().mkdirs();
            dbdir.mkdirs();
        }
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Copy database file from the assets folder
     * (long version caters for asset file name being different to the database name)
     * @param context           Context is needed to get the applicable package
     * @param dbname            name of the database file
     * @param assetfilename     name of the asset file
     * @param deleteExistingDB  true if an existing database file should be deleted
     *                              note will delete journal and wal files
     *                              note doen't actually delete the files rater it renames
     *                              the files by appended -backup to the file name
     *                              SEE/USE clearForceBackups below to delete the renamed files
     */
    public static void copyDataBase(Context context, String dbname, String assetfilename, boolean deleteExistingDB, int version) {

        checkpointIfWALEnabled(context,dbname);
        final String TAG = "COPYDATABASE";
        int stage = 0, buffer_size = 4096, blocks_copied = 0, bytes_copied = 0;
        File f = new File(context.getDatabasePath(dbname).toString());
        InputStream is;
        OutputStream os;

        /**
         * If forcing then effectively delete (rename) current database files
         */
        if (deleteExistingDB) {
            f.renameTo(context.getDatabasePath(dbname + backup));
            for (String s: tempfiles) {
                File tmpf = new File(context.getDatabasePath(dbname + s).toString());
                if (tmpf.exists()) {
                    tmpf.renameTo(context.getDatabasePath(dbname + s + backup));
                }
            }
        }

        //Open your local db as the input stream
        Log.d(TAG,"Initiated Copy of the database file " + assetfilename + " from the assets folder."); //TODO remove if publishing
        try {
            is = context.getAssets().open(assetfilename); // Open the Asset file
            stage++;
            Log.d(TAG, "Asset file " + assetfilename + " found so attmepting to copy to " + f.getPath()); //TODO remove if publishing

            os = new FileOutputStream(f);
            stage++;
            //transfer bytes from the inputfile to the outputfile
            byte[] buffer = new byte[buffer_size];
            int length;
            while ((length = is.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                blocks_copied++;
                Log.d(TAG, "Attempting copy of block " + String.valueOf(blocks_copied) + " which has " + String.valueOf(length) + " bytes."); //TODO remove if publishing
                os.write(buffer, 0, length);
                bytes_copied += length;
            }
            stage++;
            Log.d(TAG,
                    "Finished copying Database " + dbname +
                            " from the assets folder, to  " + f.getPath() +
                            String.valueOf(bytes_copied) + "were copied, in " +
                            String.valueOf(blocks_copied) + " blocks of size " +
                            String.valueOf(buffer_size) + "."
            ); //TODO remove if publishing
            //Close the streams
            os.flush();
            stage++;
            os.close();
            stage++;
            is.close();
            Log.d(TAG, "All Streams have been flushed and closed.");
            if (version > 0) {
                setVersion(context,dbname,version);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            String exception_message = "";
            e.printStackTrace();
            switch (stage) {
                case 0:
                    exception_message = "Error trying to open the asset " + dbname;
                    break;
                case 1:
                    exception_message = "Error opening Database file for output, path is " + f.getPath();
                    break;
                case 2:
                    exception_message = "Error flushing written database file " + f.getPath();
                    break;
                case 3:
                    exception_message = "Error closing written database file " + f.getPath();
                    break;
                case 4:
                    exception_message = "Error closing asset file " + f.getPath();

            }
            throw new RuntimeException("Unable to copy the database from the asset folder." + exception_message + " see starck-trace above.");
        }
    }

    /**
     * Copy the databsse from the assets folder where asset name and dbname are the same
     * @param context
     * @param dbname
     * @param deleteExistingDB
     */
    public static void copyDataBase(Context context, String dbname, boolean deleteExistingDB, int version) {
        copyDataBase(context, dbname,dbname,deleteExistingDB, version);
    }

    /**
     * Get the SQLite_user_vesrion from the DB in the asset folder
     *
     * @param context           needed to get the appropriate package assets
     * @param assetfilename     the name of the asset file (assumes/requires name matches database)
     * @return                  the version number as stored in the asset DB
     */
    public static int getVersionFromDBInAssetFolder(Context context, String assetfilename) {
        InputStream is;
        try {
            is = context.getAssets().open(assetfilename);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            return OUCH;
        }
        return getDBVersionFromInputStream(is);
    }

    /**
     * Get the version from the database itself without opening the database as an SQliteDatabase
     * @param context   Needed to ascertain package
     * @param dbname    the name of the dataabase
     * @return          the version number extracted
     */
    public static int getVersionFromDBFile(Context context, String dbname) {
        InputStream is;
        try {
            is = new FileInputStream(new File(context.getDatabasePath(dbname).toString()));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            return OUCH;
        }
        return getDBVersionFromInputStream(is);
    }

    /**
     * Get the Database Version (user_version) from an inputstream
     *  Note the inputstream is closed
     * @param is    The Inputstream
     * @return      The extracted version number
     */
    private static int getDBVersionFromInputStream(InputStream is) {
        int rv = -1, dbversion_offset = 60, dbversion_length = 4 ;
        byte[] dbfileheader = new byte[64];
        byte[] dbversion = new byte[4];
        try {
            is.read(dbfileheader);
            is.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return rv;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < dbversion_length; i++ ) {
            dbversion[i] = dbfileheader[dbversion_offset + i];
        }
        return ByteBuffer.wrap(dbversion).getInt();
    }

    /**
     * Check to see if the asset file exists
     *
     * @param context           needed to get the appropriate package
     * @param assetfilename     the name of the asset file to check
     * @return                  true if the asset file exists, else false
     */
    public static boolean ifAssetFileExists(Context context, String assetfilename) {
        try {
            context.getAssets().open(assetfilename);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }


    /**
     * Delete the backup
     * @param context
     * @param dbname
     */
    public static void clearForceBackups(Context context, String dbname) {
        String[] fulllist = new String[tempfiles.length + 1];

        for (int i = 0;i < tempfiles.length; i++) {
            fulllist[i] = tempfiles[i];
        }
        fulllist[tempfiles.length] = ""; // Add "" so database file backup is also deleted
        for (String s: fulllist) {
            File tmpf = new File(context.getDatabasePath(dbname + s + backup).toString());
            if (tmpf.exists()) {
                tmpf.delete();
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param context   The context so that the respective package is used
     * @param dbname    The name of the database (the old will have -backup appended)
     * @param table     The table from which to copy the data
     */
    public static void restoreTable(Context context, String dbname, String table) {
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        SQLiteDatabase dbnew = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(context.getDatabasePath(dbname).toString(), null,SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
        SQLiteDatabase dbold = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(context.getDatabasePath(dbname + backup).toString(),null,SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
        Cursor csr = dbold.query(table,null,null,null,null,null,null);
        dbnew.beginTransaction();
        while (csr.moveToNext()) {
            cv.clear();
            int offset = 0;
            for (String column: csr.getColumnNames()) {
                switch (csr.getType(offset++)){
                    case Cursor.FIELD_TYPE_NULL:
                        break;
                    case Cursor.FIELD_TYPE_INTEGER:
                        cv.put(column,csr.getLong(csr.getColumnIndex(column)));
                        break;
                    case Cursor.FIELD_TYPE_FLOAT:
                        cv.put(column,csr.getFloat(csr.getColumnIndex(column)));
                        break;
                    case Cursor.FIELD_TYPE_STRING:
                        cv.put(column,csr.getString(csr.getColumnIndex(column)));
                        break;
                    case Cursor.FIELD_TYPE_BLOB:
                        cv.put(column,csr.getBlob(csr.getColumnIndex(column)));
                }
            }
            dbnew.insert(DatabaseHelper.TABLE_BOOKMARK,null,cv);
        }
        dbnew.setTransactionSuccessful();
        dbnew.endTransaction();
        csr.close();
        dbnew.close();
        dbold.close();
    }

    private static void checkpointIfWALEnabled(Context context, String dbname) {
        final String TAG = "WALCHKPNT";
        Cursor csr;
        int wal_busy = -99, wal_log = -99, wal_checkpointed = -99;
        if (!new File(context.getDatabasePath(dbname).getPath()).exists()) {
            return;
        }
        SQLiteDatabase db = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(context.getDatabasePath(dbname).getPath(),null,SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
        csr = db.rawQuery("PRAGMA journal_mode",null);
        if (csr.moveToFirst()) {
            String mode = csr.getString(0);
            //Log.d(TAG, "Mode is " + mode);
            if (mode.toLowerCase().equals("wal")) {
                csr = db.rawQuery("PRAGMA wal_checkpoint",null);
                if (csr.moveToFirst()) {
                    wal_busy = csr.getInt(0);
                    wal_log = csr.getInt(1);
                    wal_checkpointed = csr.getInt(2);
                }
                //Log.d(TAG,"Checkpoint pre checkpointing Busy = " + String.valueOf(wal_busy) + " LOG = " + String.valueOf(wal_log) + " CHECKPOINTED = " + String.valueOf(wal_checkpointed) );
                csr = db.rawQuery("PRAGMA wal_checkpoint(TRUNCATE)",null);
                csr.getCount();
                csr = db.rawQuery("PRAGMA wal_checkpoint",null);
                if (csr.moveToFirst()) {
                    wal_busy = csr.getInt(0);
                    wal_log = csr.getInt(1);
                    wal_checkpointed = csr.getInt(2);
                }
                //Log.d(TAG,"Checkpoint post checkpointing Busy = " + String.valueOf(wal_busy) + " LOG = " + String.valueOf(wal_log) + " CHECKPOINTED = " + String.valueOf(wal_checkpointed) );
            }
        }
        csr.close();
        db.close();
    }

    private static void setVersion(Context context, String dbname, int version) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(context.getDatabasePath(dbname).getPath(),null,SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
        db.setVersion(version);
        db.close();

    }
}
```

An example of it's use from a DatabaseHelper (i.e. a subclass of SQLiteOpenHelper)

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private  static final String DB_NAME = "dictionary.db"; // The database file name
    private static final int DB_VERSION = 1;
    public Context mcontext;
    public SQLiteDatabase mDatabase;

    public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DB_NAME, null, DB_VERSION);
        this.mcontext = context;
        Log.d("DBVERSION","The Database Version (as hard coded) is " + String.valueOf(DB_VERSION));

        int dbversion = DatabaseAssetHandler.getVersionFromDBFile(context,DB_NAME);
        Log.d("DBVERSION","The Database Version (as per the database file) is " + String.valueOf(dbversion));

        // Copy the Database if no database exists
        if (!DatabaseAssetHandler.checkDataBase(context,DB_NAME)) {
            DatabaseAssetHandler.copyDataBase(context,DB_NAME,true,DB_VERSION);
        } else {
            // Copy the database if DB_VERSION is greater then the version stored in the database (user_version value in the db header)
            if (DB_VERSION > dbversion && DatabaseAssetHandler.checkDataBase(context, DB_NAME)) {
                DatabaseAssetHandler.copyDataBase(context, DB_NAME, true,DB_VERSION);
                DatabaseAssetHandler.restoreTable(context,DB_NAME,????THE_TABLE_NAME????); // Example of restoring a table (note ????THE_TABLE_NAME???? must be changed accordingly)
                DatabaseAssetHandler.clearForceBackups(context, DB_NAME); // Clear the backups
            }
        }
        mDatabase = this.getWritableDatabase();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    }

    // onUpgrade should not be used for the copy as may be issues due to db being opened
    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    }
}
```

1. So when constructing the database version (as per the user_version) is extracted from the file header using the **getVersionFromDBFile** method (if there is no such file then -666666 will be returned).
2. The **checkDataBase** method is used to see if the database file exists, if it doesn't then the database is copied from the assets folder.
3. Otherwise the version from the header is compared against the version number coded. If the coded version number is greater than the version number stored in the header then the database is copied, a copy of the old database file is kept.
4. The table to be restored is then restored from the old database via the **restoreTable** method (more could be restored).
5. The old copies of the database file are removed using the **clearForceBackups** method.

Comment: How do i call this new method in my DatabaseHelper class

Comment: @John example usage added.

Comment: I added crashlytics to my app and i'm getting a lot of crashes on  ` SQLiteDatabase dbOld = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(context.getDatabasePath(dbName + backup).toString(),null,SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);`

Comment: @John I've never used crashlytics, so I have no idea about that.

Comment: There's no bookmark table in the backup database, you need to check that the backup database is valid/usable or that you are specifying the correct table name(s).

Comment: i have created it manually in my database it works fine for me on emulator and on real device

Comment: If you have `android:allowBackup="true"` in your manifest try changing it to **false**. Other thing to do is add lines `Cursor csr = dbold.query("sqlite_master,null,null,null,null,null,null);` and `DatabaseUtils.dumpCursor(csr);` before the line `Cursor csr = dbold.query(table,null,null,null,null,null,null);`. All tables indexes views triggers etc should be written to the log.