# How to import a database in application assets into a database in the app storage?

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite

I am developping an Android application in java. This app needs data that is shipped in the apk to function. I have a SQLite database in the app's assets. This database has a single table. I only need read access to this table.

I also want to have data that is created at runtime (also in a single table). I am looking for a way to have both working effiently.

As far as I have read online, it does not seem possible to read the database from the assets without copying the database to the app's storage. My idea was to have two tables in the application database. The first table should be copied from the database in the assets in the first run. The second table is used normally at app runtime. The database shipped with the application also may get updates from time to time so I would need a way to not loose user data when updating it.

Is this a recommended way of doing things and if it is, how would I achieve this? And would you recommend Room for such a use case?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54822935/which-methods-can-be-used-to-manage-differing-versions-of-pre-existing-databases

Comment: Hey this seems to be a common topic. Does this thread help you? 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513084/ship-an-application-with-a-database?rq=2